# Cannot mark file as executable (?)

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, cuda, permissions, executable

[**Note**:] I first thought the problem was caused by CUDA, but it was only because of my filesystem (see in answers) - so this could belong to any program, if anybody else got stuck here.

**The Problem**

I try to program with my NVIDIA-GPU on Ubuntu, with the help of CUDA.

When I'm compiling everything works fine - no errors, no warnings. But in the end I get an executable I cannot open, I get the message *Permission denied*. When I check the access rights I see that file isn't "marked as executable". If I try to set it, that box immediately gets unchecked again. Even commands like

```
sudo chmod +x ./myprogram
```

don't work (the rights stay the same as they were).

**What I did**

I installed

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and afterwards

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential freeglut3-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa-dev libx11-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev
```

The code itself should be alright, since it's working perfectly on every other machine but just not on my Ubuntu/GPU combination (?).

**The according CMakesLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( gpuSobel )
find_package( CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message("CUDA found!")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -O3 -lineinfo -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=compute_35)

    set(CUDASRCS 
        main.cu
    )

    CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(gpuSobel ${CUDASRCS})

else()
    message("CUDA not found, abort")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

# SSE support
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse -msse2 -msse3")
endif()

target_link_libraries( gpuSobel ${OpenCV_LIBS} )


add_custom_command(TARGET gpuSobel POST_BUILD
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/images
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:gpuSobel>/images)
```

Please somebody enlighten me why even `sudo` is powerless here, is it a compile- or a Linux-error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out I was compiling/accessing the compiled file on a partition that doesn't support access rights. When I copied it to my home (`~/`) directory I could set the access rights and execute the file afterwards.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen  http://bikulov.org/blog/2013/12/24/example-of-cmake-file-for-cuda-plus-cpp-code/ ?? 
I always use their code for Cmake.

Comment: yah I'm sorry I forgot the makefile. Please have a look at my updated top post

Comment: create CMakeLists.txt file and place it in your sources directory. Then create bin directory next to src. Change directory to bin, generate Makefile from CMakeLists.txt and build it with ordinary make.